# How to embed RTMP live-stream?

Tags: html, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I want to embed an RTMP Live Stream in a HTML document. I want to use HTML5 instead of flash (That it can work under *nix/osx/mobile devices).

How can I do this? Do I need to use 3rd party libraries? When yes: Can you recommend one?

I've found an answer on StackOverflow but it wasn't very helpful. Since the answer was from 2011 I guess it's okay to ask this question again.

Comment: I would highly recommend posting what you have tried in your question as well as the previous SO Q/A you found.

Comment: Note that question age is generally not all that relevant; what matters is whether the question (and its answers) apply to what you're doing or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTMP was designed for Flash and works with Flash. I'm not aware of a way to embed it in HTML5 without a Flash engine.

Considering the above you could:

- write or find a specialized player that can talk to a RTMP server and
  play the stream without Flash, but this beats your intention of
  embedding the video in a web page

or

- create two streams based on the same source for each target device. This can be achieved by transcoding the source material in multiple formats or live transcoding and re-streaming of the RTMP source. You could use HLS as an alternative protocol which is supported on a greater number of platforms, even if it has its hiccups with certain versions of Android (especially 4.4.3 and 4.4.4)

There are paid and freeware solutions for RTMP re-streaming, like Nimble or Wowza Streaming Engine to name a few.